# Passing Vector by reference C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, python-re

I am passing a string vector by reference, but the changes don't persist to the original variable. If I read all the strings at the end of StringFormatter, they will be correctly formatted. However, if I print out the strings as shown in main(), it will not show any of the modifications.

```
void StringFormatter(std::vector<std::string> &instructions){
    for(auto it = instructions.begin(); it < instructions.end(); it++){     
        /*Remove any line which has character ;
         Logic here doesn't really pertain to my question
         Tons more formatting in here, but not relevant.*/

        size_t pos = (*it).find_first_of(";",0);
        if(pos != std::string::npos){
            instructions.erase(it);
        } 
    }
}

int main(){
    /* instructions is populated through reading a text file*/
    /* vector of instructions is populated for us */

    StringFormatter(instructions);
    /*I want the changes made to instructions in StringFormatter() to modify the 
     original instructions variable in main()*/


    for(auto it = instructions.begin(); it < instructions.end(); it++){
        printf("%s\n", (*it).c_str());
    } 

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you put example instructions from text file?

Comment: Include comments in your code what you aim to do. The code is a bit ... unclear.

Comment: After `instructions.erase(it);`, `it` is invalid. That means the `it++` in the for loop is in for quite an adventure.

Comment: The `erase()` call invalidates your iterators.

Comment: *they will be correctly formatted* -- What does this mean?  What is the goal of the function `StringFormatter`?  Maybe if you stated what it was, there would be a better way of accomplishing that goal rather than `erase` in a loop.

Comment: You may find the [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) helpful.

Comment: @OP [Is this what you're trying to do?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd8cf7042f34c83)

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Thanks, the ampersand for the iterator solved my main issue. Also good to know about the erase-remove idiom!